# How to write a unit test case for the api calls made in ngOnInit function in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to write a test case for an api call in ngOnInit function which is as follows:

```
let getDomainApi:string = "http://example.com";
    this.apiService.get(getDomainApi)
     .subscribe(
        domains => {
          this.domains = domains;
        },
       (err:HttpErrorResponse) => {
         let message : any = {};
         message = err;
         var toastOptions:ToastOptions = {
           title: "Alert",
           msg: message,
           showClose: true,
           timeout: 5000,
           theme: 'default'
         };
         this.toastyService.error(toastOptions); 
        }
    );
```

Test Case is as follows:

```
{describe('getDistricts()', () => {
it('should return an Observable<Array<districts>>',
  inject([ApiService, XHRBackend], (apiService, mockBackend) => {
    component.selectState('KARNATAKA');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const getDistrictsApi = "http://example.com";
    const mockResponse = {
      data: [
        "Belgaum", "Bagalkot"
      ]
    };
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `xyz`);
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
      expect(connection.request.url).toEqual(getDistrictsApi);
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
        body: JSON.stringify(mockResponse)
      })));
    });
    apiService.get(getDistrictsApi, {headers}).subscribe((districts) => {
      expect(districts.length).toBe(1);
    });
  })
);
});
```

But the response is of the actual ts file rather than of the stubbed data. How can I proceed?

Comment: Would you give this a try and let us know what _specific_ problem you run into? What are you having trouble with in particular?

Comment: Actually when i wrote the test case and mocked the data too still then it is calling the actual data and which is there in the ts file rather than the stubbed data.